# Dynamic Authorization Attributes for MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I am using `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` which inherits `AuthorizeAttribute`.

My authorization context is based on `Role` for a user accessing it.

But I ran into a scenario, where user `Roles` can be added or deleted from system in future.

for a few controller and action scenario, Attribute decoration can be changed easily.

Eg, for new role (Manager) in Authorization

```
 [CustomAuthorize(Roles = UserRoles.Administrator  )]
```

will need to be modified as

```
 [CustomAuthorize(Roles = UserRoles.Administrator + "," + UserRoles.Manager )]
```

My Question is **how do we manage new `Roles` in the system for Apps having lots of controller and actions**.

Any dynamic ways to do so?

Comment: You can try reading the claims of authenticated user and whether that user's group has  access to particular Uri(s) as permission. The admin can then manage the group, uri permissions from admin panel.

Comment: If it were me, I would remove the roles and use intent of the action/controller instead.  So rather than saying that Address/Edit action can be called by Managers, you would add that specific ability to the user.  It will mean you have a lot more permissions in the db though, but you would add those permissions to a role, and then using the role, look to see if that role has that functional permission.